# Jeschurun in English

Tags: product-recommendation, samson-raphael-hirsch

Is ther an English version of R' Hirsch's journal, *Jeschurun* available? While I am currently learning German, I am far from being competent enough to understand the works of R' Hirsch in the original.

Comment: If you know Yiddish, Deutsch should not be a problem. ;)

Comment: @EzraHoerster In that case, we can conclude the OP doesn't know Yiddish that well, as he says his German is not good enough. In any event, how does your comment help him?

Comment: @EzraHoerster, my grasp of Yiddish isn't much better than your average American Modern Orthodox Jew, which is to say it's fairly bad.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Yiddish is [surprisingly] extremely easy to learn. Try looking for some online sources...that's how I learned for the most part. Then, after that, find some Yiddish speakers to schmooze with and you'll learn quick. ;) Six months, tops. (At least, that's how it was for me.)

Answer (score 3):

Kessinger Publishing has an edition in English that can be found on various sites including Amazon and Ebay. Though I cannot personally attest to the quality of the translation, there do not seem to be alternatives available for such an old book.

This edition *does* come with the German original as well, should your German skills improve.

Source: [Jeschurun (1864)](http://www.abebooks.com/9781104263928/Jeschurun-1864-Kobak-Joseph-1104263920/plp)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ariel! Thanks for sharing your valuable information. Hopefully you will choose to stick around and continue contributing. Consider reading this [Beginners' Guide to the Site](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) which explains what distinguishes this site from others. For more information see the [Help Center](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: The jescgurun in your link is not the jeschurun of Rav Hirsch. See https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/judaica/ejud_0002_0011_0_10096.html JESCHURUN, name of several Hebrew and German or German-Hebrew periodicals. The best known were:

(1) An Orthodox monthly published in German by Samson Raphael *Hirsch at Frankfurt (16 vols., 1854–70), and later issued as a weekly by his son Isaac Hirsch at Hanover (1883–88). Hirsch's famous polemics against Z. *Frankeland H. *Graetz first appeared in thisJeschurun.

Comment: (2) A less polemical and more scholarly periodical of moderate Conservative tendencies published by Joseph I. Kobak. This appeared with interruptions between 1856 and 1878 (nine volumes) at Lemberg, Breslau, Fuerth, and Bamberg. The first volume was in Hebrew only, the remainder in Hebrew and German. The contributors included L. *Dukes, S.D. *Luzzatto, S.J. *Rapoport, J. *Reifmann, M. *Steinschneider, and D. *Cassel.

(3) An Orthodox German-language monthly published by J. *Wohlgemuthduring the years 1914–30 (17 volumes).